# How to save 10 different id from Jmeter response and use it in next 10 requests

Tags: jmeter

I am currently running 10 different threads like this:

each of the thread response will provide a different id in the response and i want to save them and use it as a request in the next test case(10 threads) so there will be 10 ids and 10 threads and each thread will have a unique id as a request. This is what I am doing:

Here is the first request

This is how I am extracting the values

This is how i am using the final request however i am not able to get the desired results

**UPDATE:**

**I tried Dmitri Answer but still no luck i am extracting the id by using this**

I used __threadNum() function as the prefix or postfix for the property name like:

```
${__setProperty(loginassistant_${__threadNum},${loginassistant_},)}
```

and read it similarly:

```
${__P(loginassistant_${__threadNum},)}
```

but it is not working and it is setting the value as a static string(see screenshot below):

This is how and where i am defining my loginassistant using the simple controller:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using properties which are global, if you have more than one thread the next thread will **overwrite** the property defined by the previous thread so it could be mismatch.

If you don't need to pass values across thread groups - go for [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) instead, variables are local to the thread (virtual user) and the properties are global for the whole JMeter/JVM instance

If you do need to pass values across thread groups - either use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as the prefix or postfix for the property name like:

```
${__setProperty(loginassistant_${__threadNum},${loginassistant},)}
```

and read it similarly:

```
${__P(loginassistant_${__threadNum},)}
```

or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)

Comment: Do i still need to extract the login_assistant? when i set the variables above it is adding bar in the next request instead of the loginassistant id

Comment: does the threadnum even work with the approach i am using?

Comment: You have unnecessary underscore, it should look like `${__setProperty(loginassistant_${__threadNum},${loginassistant},)}`

Comment: I have no  idea where do you define your login_assistant_X variable, if it is not defined - you will have default value of 1

Comment: It does work, unfortunately my crystal ball doesn't, your screnshot is very nice but it doesn't act like the evidence of the variable being defined, check if it's really there using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/). The same applies to properties.